# My mod_rewrite not ignoring existing files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Writing a CMS in PHP and using Apache .htaccess for my redirects. I have a filesystem like this:

```
/MySites [dir]
    /MySite1.com [dir]
        /css [dir]
            style.css [file]
        /pages [dir]
    /MySite2.com [dir]
    compiler.php [file]
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) compiler.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ compiler.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This, `//localhost/MySites/MySite1.com/home` (no `.htm`) goes to `compiler.php?id=MySite1.com/home`. Good...

But existing files like `//localhost/MySites/MySite1.com/css/style.css` get redirected too: `compiler.php?id=MySite1.com/css/style.css`. Bad...

What's wrong with my `RewriteRule`'s?

Comment: `RewriteCond` only applies to the next `RewriteRule`, not both. So your second rule is rewriting for everything that matches the pattern `^(.*)/` which is pretty much everything.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Given that your two Rules differ by only a single char, you could just have `^(.*)/?` and you'd probably have things working as expected.

Comment: Alright, that worked. For some reason, though, I can't get `^(.*)` to capture everything so I had to add that second line... I don't know why that is.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, if you'd write that in the answer I'd accept it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteCond` only applies to the next `RewriteRule`, not both. So your second rule is rewriting for everything that matches the pattern `^(.*)/` which is pretty much everything.

Comment: Hey, would you know why requesting `//localhost/MySites/MySite1.com` would keep redirecting to `//localhost/MySites/MySite1.com/?id=MySite1.com` (`.htaccess` is doing it, not my script) and how to stop it? Not a major issue, but defeats the purpose of pretty URLs. (BTW, I made the changes you mentioned.)

Comment: Is it redirecting? Or rewriting? They are different. A redirect actually changes the url in your browser. A rewrite you see the pretty url, but the page with the ugly url is loaded behind the scenes. When you go to `//localhost/MySites/MySite1.com/` does it actually change you to `//localhost/MySites/MySite1.com/?id=MySite1.com`?

Comment: Yes, my browser actually changes the URL, so it's redirecting apparently. If I add the trailing slash, it doesn't do that. My rules are `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteRule ^(.*)/? compiler.php?id=$1 [L]`